# Waiting for IdThreadComponent to finish on program exit

Tags: multithreading, delphi, c++builder, indy

I am trying to utilize shared function (in main thread) and use it from 3 threads. The function will do some potentially lengthy operation like disk write and to avoid possible problems I will lock it. I use Indy `IdThreadComponent` and `TCriticalSection`. Here is how it looks:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// In header file
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
boost::scoped_ptr<TCriticalSection> csShared;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main file
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{
csShared.reset(new TCriticalSection);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::SharedFunction(UnicodeString TextData)
{
try
    {
    csShared->Enter();           // As suggested by Remy this is placed incorrectly and needs to be moved outside of try block
    //Memo1->Lines->Add(TextData); // [EDIT] calling this within thread is wrong
    Sleep(2000);
    }
__finally
    {
    csShared->Leave();
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdThreadComponent1Run(TIdThreadComponent *Sender)
{
SharedFunction("Thread 1 calling");
IdThreadComponent1->Stop();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdThreadComponent2Run(TIdThreadComponent *Sender)
{
SharedFunction("Thread 2 calling");
IdThreadComponent2->Stop();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdThreadComponent3Run(TIdThreadComponent *Sender)
{
SharedFunction("Thread 3 calling");
IdThreadComponent3->Stop();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
IdThreadComponent1->Start();
IdThreadComponent2->Start();
IdThreadComponent3->Start();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCloseQuery(TObject *Sender, bool &CanClose)
{
// Note - these 3 Stop() calls are used if threads are set to run infinitely
// But in this example it is not needed as they stop themselves
//IdThreadComponent1->Stop();
//IdThreadComponent2->Stop();
//IdThreadComponent3->Stop();

// Now wait for lock to be released [WRONG - COMMENTED IN EDIT]
//while (!csShared->TryEnter())
//  {
//  Sleep(500);
//  }
//csShared->Leave();

// [EDIT v1] easier and faster way to wait than above
//csShared->Enter();
//csShared->Leave();

// [EDIT v2] block exit until all threads are done
while (IdThreadComponent1->Active || IdThreadComponent2->Active || IdThreadComponent3->Active)
{
Sleep(200); // make wait loop less CPU intensive
};

CanClose = true;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problems:

<strike>- If I close window quickly (only one thread executes the function, it never leaves program - waits forever, and in debugger only first thread exits, other two don't). I am using OnCloseQuery event to check if threads are done. What I am doing wrong?</strike>

[EDIT] After removing `Memo1->Lines->Add(TextData);` as suggested in comments by David Heffernan, it exits properly so this part of question is solved and the following remains:

- Is it fine to call `csShared->Enter();` inside the shared function like above or do I have to call it outside of it in each thread like this:

  ```
  void __fastcall TForm1::IdThreadComponent1Run(TIdThreadComponent *Sender)
  {
  csShared->Enter();
  SharedFunction("Thread 1 calling");
  csShared->Leave();
  IdThreadComponent1->Stop();
  }
  ```
- Is this better than the above version (calling `csShared->Enter();` within the function itself)? Or the same? Both versions seem to work fine, I am wondering is there a difference, because the first one is cleaner.

I do not need `Synchronize` in case if you are wondering, this will be for disk write and not for updating VCL, so the above SharedFunction is just for the example purpose.

Comment: Do you know that you are not allowed to do GUI work away from the GUI thread. Your program appears to violate that rule.

Comment: Let's suppose that I don't put things in Memo in that function. The shared function is just an example but in reality it would be something that writes to disk and is potentially lengthy.

Comment: Ooops... looks like the code does exit properly when I remove `Memo1->Lines->Add(TextData);` looks like that is the error here. But what about other questions about `csShared->Enter();` calls?

Comment: That loop around the TryEnter is a disaster. Just call Enter. That will block until the lock is aquired.

Comment: I guess this answers my other question too - about placement of `csShared->Enter();` call, it implies that both versions are fine.

Comment: In general you want a policy that locks are held for as short a time as possible. To minimise contention on the lock. That's often the overriding concern.

Comment: The code in close query is still wrong. I can't work out what you are trying to do? Do you want to block until all threads are complete?

Comment: Exactly, block until threads finish (for example disk to save data), and it works just fine. May not be the nicest thing to look at but it works. I could though employ other methods of waiting for threads to finish, perhaps to check `IdThreadComponent->Active` flag in this case. It will do for this example though.

Comment: No, it does not work. It does not block until the threads finish. It just aquires and then releases a lock. If you want to block until something happens you need a wait function.

Comment: You are right, of course. I do need proper wait function. This worked in this example. I edited the post again and included checking of `Active` flag. Tested and it works.

Comment: That's still not a great wait function because it will spin at 100% CPU.

Comment: You have a problem for every solution :) But once again you're right. I'll look into other methods of waiting for threads to finish or introduce a small enough Sleep().

Comment: Well, it's my view that `Sleep` is never the answer. At least not in programming. It may be the answer in life!!  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine, even desirable, to put the calls to `Enter()` and `Leave()` inside of the shared function.  However, if you are going to use `try/__finally` then you need to put the `Enter()` outside of the `try`, in case it fails.  You don't want to `Leave()` something you did not successful `Enter()` into, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::SharedFunction(UnicodeString TextData)
{
    csShared->Enter();
    try
    {
        //...
        Sleep(2000);
    }
    __finally
    {
        csShared->Leave();
    }
}

void __fastcall TForm1::IdThreadComponent1Run(TIdThreadComponent *Sender)
{
    SharedFunction("Thread 1 calling");
    IdThreadComponent1->Stop();
}
```

Since you are using Boost anyway, you should make use of its own `mutex` and `lock` classes instead, then you don't have to worry about `try/__finally`, `Enter()`, or `Leave()` at all, eg:

```
#include <boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>

boost::recursive_mutex mutex;

void __fastcall TForm1::SharedFunction(UnicodeString TextData)
{
    boost::lock_guard<boost::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex);
    //...
    Sleep(2000);
}
```

As for the `TMemo` access, use the `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class to execute that code in a thread-safe manner, eg:

```
#include <IdSync.hpp>

class TMemoNotify : public TIdNotify
{
protected:
    String TextData;

    void __fastcall DoNotify()
    {
        Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(TextData);
    }

public:
    __fastcall TMemoNotify(const String &ATextData) : TextData(ATextData) {}
};


void __fastcall TForm1::SharedFunction(UnicodeString TextData)
{
    ...
    (new TMemoNotify(TextData))->Notify(); // TIdNotify is self-freeing
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just another in series of your excellent answers Remy! Always spot on to the point.

Comment: I may just correct you that the correct header for recursive mutex is `#include <boost/thread/recursive_mutex.hpp>`

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to utilize shared function (in main thread) and use it from 3 threads.

A method or procedure (generally a piece of code) does not belong to a thread *per se*. Any piece of code can potentially be called from any thread within the application, and it can be running multiple times at the same time if called from different threads in a concurrent fashion.

For example

```
procedure A();
begin
  //do some work.
end;
```

You can have a execution like this:

```
main thread
     |
  SomeFunc();
     |
     |      spawns
     |     thread X  
     |---------|
     |         |
     |         |
     |      OtherF()
    A()        |
     |         |   spawns thread Y
     |         |-------------|
     |        A()            |
     |         |             |
     |         |            A()
     |         |             | 
     |         |             |
  t1>|         |             |
     |         |             |
   A returns   |             |
    B()        |             |
     |         |             |
  t2>|         |             |
     |         |             |
     |        A returns      |
     |        thread end     |
     |                       |
     |                       |
  t3>|                       |
     |                      A returns
     |                      thread end
     |
   program end
```

At t1, 3 different threads are running the function A(), at t2, 2 thread are still running it (X and Y) and at t3 only one thread executes that function (thread Y).

> Is it fine to call csShared->Enter(); inside the shared function like above or do I have to call it outside of it in each thread like this:

This is up to you. You have to define where to call it, as you are the responsible to define what pieces of code must be running only in the context of one thread while others will be waiting for this to finish to start (serial execution).

- If the entire function body is to be *serialized*, I think it's better to put the critical section Enter inside the function (as the first line), since IMHO this leads to cleaner code in the calling sites, while ensuring you can't forget to enter the critical section before calling the function.
- If the function call is part of a more complex operation, you have to call the CriticalSection enter at the start of that operation, obviusly outside the function body.
- It is possible also to have parts of the function that can be running in parallel, so you must favor concurrency and call the CriticalSection.Enter only when needed inside your function.

Remember each CriticalSection is a bottleneck. A intentional one, but you have to use it with caution to avoid introducing waits where is not really needed.

Comment: Of course it is bottleneck, but so is disk-operation and functions need consistent disk-data (where I will actually apply this), therefore blocking is needed. Excellent answer though, I would mark this one as answer but I can only mark one and Remy's was just a little bit more to the point. So I up-voted this (and others should too, both are great answers), anyway I appreciate your explanation! I'm learning a lot here.